# periodic in $x$ with period $2\pi$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, closed-form, periodic-functions

What it means for a function to be

> periodic in $x$ with period $\frac{2\pi}{\log(2)}$ ?

When I plug in $2^x$ in Wolfram Alpha I get this information.

Does it have something to do with the Euler number $e$ or $\pi$, derivation or integrals? Because Ive seen some constant number raised to some radi which represented angles, but i forgot about it. Because it feels periodicity has something to do with angles of some rotation in it? But it can also be a loop? or am I on a blueberry trip.

I also wonder if some function is periodic, does it link to closed-form expression or can they not be connected.

I read that

> a periodic function is a function that repeats its values in regular
>   intervals or periods

but how can $2^x$ repeat itself if $x$ is increasing sequentially? Is it just that $x$ on the Reals can be periodic $x$ is a sine function?

Comment: I would expect the period to be $2\pi i / \log(2)$, note that $e^{x+2\pi i} = e^{x}$

Comment: @RolfHoyer If so, whats the reason Wolfram alpha omits $i$ in that expression?

Comment: Wolfram alpha says that $e^x$ is periodic in $x$ with period $2i\pi $, as expected

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Im talking about $2^x$

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy:  I know; I'm just saying that for $e$ instead of $2$, wolfram alpha says what we'd expect

Comment: Its obviously a small bug in the software. One can find plenty of similar bugs in WA (try to search "bugs Wolfram Alpha" here)